# Missingness in the Outcome and Predictor Variables Using a Synthetic Controls Design

Tags: r, causality, synthetic-controls

I am working with a data set that has missing values in both the outcome (for both the treated and non-treated units) and the predictors. Overall, these missing values represent a small portion of all observations (1-10%, depending on the predictor/cross-sectional unit), but it is enough to create errors when I attempt to create the synthetic controls using the `tidysynth` package.

Unfortunately, the missing data I have is not missing in an ordered fashion. That is, within the `tidysynth` package, I cannot specify a predictor within a certain time frame as both available and missing data per predictor are scattered all over the place temporally. Otherwise, I would simply specify the years in which these predictors had no missingness. Further, even if I could do this, it doesn’t solve the random NA values in my outcome variable.

I’ll briefly list some of the solutions I’ve considered and why I think they may be problematic:

- One approach would be to re-specify the time variable as a count of years (1, 2, 3, …) rather than (1991, 1992, 1994 …) so that there are no artificial gaps. However, NA values in both the outcome and predictors differs by year per cross-sectional unit. This means that using this method could result in a temporal count variable that incorrectly represents the temporal ordering of observations (for unit A, the 5th time period could be 1995 while, due to missingness, the 5th time period for unit B could be 1998, etc.)
- To remove missingness in general, I could take the average of the year prior and the year following the NA value and average this. But it feels like this approach seriously muddies any causal effect that can be derived from the method as I would do this to fill in missing values for both the outcome and the predictors.

Any ideas or suggestions? I imagine missingness is a common issue with the synthetic control method so I’m curious on what are legitimate strategies to combat this.

Comment: I am a bit confused, why would we want to use instances where the *outcome* is missing? By definition that is our research question, if we could estimate accurately enough then we wouldn't need the sampling anyway. Similarly for the case that only a few predictors are missing. Why not try some "standard" imputation techniques first (e.g. PPCA and MICE) and see how their results look? If they look very different to each other, OK, problem, if not really different, no problem, imputation is not strongly affecting the insights gained...